# Finding gender affinity for businesses

Tags: nlp, machine-learning-model, probability

What are the different models I can use to find the gender affinity of businesses using yelp dataset-- https://www.kaggle.com/yelp-dataset/yelp-dataset . I need to find Probablity (Male buying from a merchant) and Probablity (Female buying from a merchant) where both probablities add to 1 . There is no information about gender so I can use the Genderize api to find gender using names of users. This is an unsupervised problem

Comment: Do you just want to find the gender affinity of the businesses in the dataset?  Or are you hoping to build a model to predict gender affinity for new businesses?

Comment: just in the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only interested in the gender affinity of businesses in your dataset, no model is needed.  You can compute gender affinity directly:  For each business, find the total number of customers, the total number of male customers, and the total number of female customers.  Then $Pr(Male) = \frac{males}{total}$ and $Pr(Female) = \frac{females}{total}$